What Digital Signature Methods are Suitable for Microcontrollers?
Given the constraints in terms of processing power, memory, and energy, what digital signature schemes are commonly used and efficient for Microcontrollers? I have come across RSA with low public exponents and the Rabin signature scheme. Are there other methods, such as ECDSA or Ed25519, that are feasible and practical for these microcontrollers? Any insights or references to implementations would be greatly appreciated.
Note: I am working on implementing digital signatures on an Arduino ATmega 2560 R3.

Would the Microcontroller be signing, or will it be only verifying signatures? And, what's the use case (stateful hash based signatures work well in some cases, but not others)?

@poncho ,  signing and verifying signatures ... what do you mean by (stateful hash based signatures work well in some cases, but not others) please ?

For embedded systems, it's recommended to lean towards ECC instead of RSA because it provides benefits like smaller keys, quicker processing times, and lesser demands on memory, energy, and bandwidth.
In your case, you are interested in deploying digital signatures on an 8-bit AVR microprocessor. Several works have been conducted to optimize ECC-based signatures on this platform.
Notably, this work from Hutter and Schwabe reports around 32 million clock cycles to compute an Ed25519 signature on the ATmega2560.
To concretely illustrate the performance benefits over RSA, this work from Liu, Großschädl and Kizhvatov reports around 76 million clock cycles to compute an RSA-1024 signature on the ATmega128.
Note that both implementation above-mentioned run in constant-time, which is of utmost importance, especially for embedded systems.

Right, when needing to generate a signature or a private key on an embedded system. But when only needing to quickly verify  a signature, RSA signature is like 10 times faster even with e=65537 (and e=3 saves a further factor like 5; the less common Rabin signature makes that like 10). It's quite OK to have some things externally signed with RSA (e.g. public key certificates, executable code signature), and all the rest EdDSA. That's one reason why certification authorities still often sign with RSA.

Well, there are short signature https://github.com/mattrglobal/bbs-signatures
